# groupby category and sum the count

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I have a table (df) like so:

```
    type count
    A    5000
    B    5000
    C    200
    D    123
    ...  ...
    ...  ...
    Z    453
```

How can I sum the column `count` by type `A`, `B` and all other types fall into `Others` category?

I currently have this:

```
df = df.withColumn('type', when(col("type").isnot("A", "B"))
```

My expected output would be like so:

```
type  count
A     5000
B     5000
Other 3043
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to group by when expression and sum the count :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.groupBy(
    when(
        F.col("type").isin("A", "B"), F.col("type")
    ).otherwise("Others").alias("type")
).agg(
    F.sum("count").alias("count")
)
    
df1.show()

#+------+-----+
#|  type|count|
#+------+-----+
#|     B| 5000|
#|     A| 5000|
#|Others|  776|
#+------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can divide the dataframe into two parts based on the type, aggregate a sum for the second part, and do a `unionAll` to combine them.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

result = df.filter("type in ('A', 'B')").unionAll(
    df.filter("type not in ('A', 'B')")
      .select(F.lit('Other'), F.sum('count'))
)

result.show()
+-----+-----+
| type|count|
+-----+-----+
|    A| 5000|
|    B| 5000|
|Other|  776|
+-----+-----+
```