# Sum values of specific rows if fields are the same

Tags: pyspark

Hi Im trying to sum values of one column if 'ID' matches for all in a dataframe

For example

| ID | Gender | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Male | 5 |
| 1 | Male | 6 |
| 2 | Female | 3 |
| 3 | Female | 0 |
| 3 | Female | 9 |
| 4 | Male | 10 |

How do I get the following table

| ID | Gender | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Male | 11 |
| 2 | Female | 3 |
| 3 | Female | 9 |
| 4 | Male | 10 |

In the example above, ID with Value 1 is now showed just once and its value has been summed up (same for ID with value 3).

Thanks

Im new to Pyspark and still learning. I've tried count(), select and groupby() but nothing has resulted in what Im trying to do.

Comment: very basic -- isn't this just a simple groupBy with sum aggregation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [groupby category and sum the count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66337545/groupby-category-and-sum-the-count)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
df = (
    df
    .withColumn('value', f.sum(f.col('value')).over(Window.partitionBy(f.col('ID'))))
)
```

Link to documentation about `Window` operation https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.window.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple [`groupBy`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.groupBy.html), with the [`sum`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.sum.html) function:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

(
    df
    .groupby("ID", 'Gender')  # sum rows with same ID and Gender
    # .groupby("ID")  # use this line instead if you want to sum rows with the same ID, even if they have different Gender
    .agg(F.sum('value').alias('value'))
)
```

The result is:

```bash
+---+------+-----+
| ID|Gender|value|
+---+------+-----+
|  1|  Male|   11|
|  2|Female|    3|
|  3|Female|    9|
|  4|  Male|   10|
+---+------+-----+
```